# Draw outside ScrollView

Tags: android

I'm using TwoDScrollView, but for sake of simplicity let's say I have a very simple layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/rootLayout"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:paddingTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <View
    android:id="@+id/topOverview"
    android:background="#cc000000"
    android:layout_above="@+id/scrollView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:clipChildren="false"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp">

    <ImageView
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:src="@drawable/my_photo"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </ScrollView>

    <View
    android:id="@+id/bottomOverview"
    android:background="#cc000000"
    android:layout_below="@+id/scrollView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

So I have a scrollView with ImageView inside (which is bigger ofc). Now I want to also draw what's outside scrollview. I also want to cover this area with 80% alpha-black views (using layout_above and layout_below) as you can see in xml. Thanks to that user will be able see area outside scrollview, but it will look different outside. I've tried clipChildren, but I doesn't work. It's still clipped anyway.

I've achieved this very easily on iOS by just one line of code (plus view above and below scrollView with correct constraints):

```
scrollView.clipsToBounds = false
```

It looks like that:

[image]

So how can I achieve it on Android? Canvas is too much for this I think. I've also came up with an idea that I can duplicate ImageView outside ScrollView, place it below it and move it as scroll moves. But is there an easier method?